# Rails and pie.htc does not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pie-chart

I put in pie.htc

```
alert('works');
```

and move pie.htc to every folder of my project.

in css i try to do this:

```
behavior: url('/assets/pie.htc');
behavior: url(/assets/pie.htc);
behavior: url('pie.htc');
behavior: url('/public/pie.htc');
```

But it does not load - i dont see any alert for pie.htc.

What I should write in my css and where put this pie file.

Comment: The first url should work if you are putting your file in the assets folder. One thing to keep in mind (which caused me much trouble) is that pie.htc is ONLY loaded when IE is used. If you use Firefox, Chrome, etc. the alert will not be shown because pie.htc is never loaded. So, be sure to use IE to check if it is working.

Comment: ok thanks... i check it in chrome but now check in ie and havent got any alert also... im beginner and when i see my site on ie ..OMG! no gradient, strange borders, not every img loaded and fonts... there is no fonts (right now i try to load .eot font but also nothing change)..

Comment: Are you sure your pie.htc file is in your assets/stylesheets folder? Also, try using -> behavior: url(/assets/pie.htc); without the single quote commas

Comment: PIE works, i do not see it in chrome but works in IE. I put my PIE.htc in public folder and in css use ('/pie.htc') and it works.